# Average for group no within group - stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

How to compute an average value for group using stream. Below code which I would like to transform to stream solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
        new Item("A", 1.0),
        new Item("A", 1.0),
         new Item("B", 1.0)
    );

    System.out.println(averageForGroup(items));
}

public static double  averageForGroup(List<Item> items) {
    Set<String> uniqueGroups = new HashSet<>();
    double sum = 0;
    for (Item i : items) {
        String groupName = i.getGroupName();

        if (!uniqueGroups.contains(groupName)) {
            uniqueGroups.add(groupName);
        }
        sum += i.getValue();
    }

     return sum / uniqueGroups.size();
}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {

    private String groupName;
    private Double value;

    // Full-args constructor
    // Getters and setters
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
public static double  averageForGroup2(List<Item> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Item::getGroupName, 
                    Collectors.averagingDouble(Item::getValue)) )
                .entrySet().stream()
                .mapToDouble(entry -> entry.getValue())
                .sum();
}
```

But method sums up averages, so not what I expect. If it was possible to revert summing with grouping it may return excepted result.

Comment: Can you post expected result and some rationale behind it? Also `if (!uniqueGroups.contains(groupName)) { uniqueGroups.add(groupName); }` should only be `uniqueGroups.add(groupName);` since `Set#add` already checks if set contains value or not.

Comment: For now I am under impression that you may just replace `Collectors.summarizingDouble(Item::getValue)` with `Collectors.averagingDouble(Item::getValue)` in your `averageForGroup2` method and get rid of rest of `.entrySet().stream()...` part.

Comment: To first comment: You are right, it may be write simpler. To second:  Yes it shoul be  averagingDouble. I will correct it.

Comment: My second comment wasn't meant to be clarification of question, but potential solution to "How to compute average value for group using stream". The quoted part suggest that you want to calculate average value for *each* group separately which Collectors.averagingDouble(Item::getValue) does. But based on your `for(..)` loop example it looks like it is not what you want. If I understand you correctly you want to calculate sum of all values and divide it by amount of unique group names. If that is the case then your current solution would be probably more efficient than one from accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it seems some problems can be solved simpler without streams. I mean simpler to code, at least for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double result = items.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.groupingBy(
                                    Item::getGroupName,
                                    Collectors.summingDouble(Item::getValue)),
                            map -> map.values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum() / map.size()));
```

To make it more readable, you can do it in two operations:

```
long distinct = items.stream().map(Item::getGroupName).distinct().count();
double sums = items.stream().mapToDouble(Item::getValue).sum();

System.out.println(sums / distinct);
```

You can do it in a single pass, but requires a custom collector...

Comment: second one is much better IMO

Comment: upvote for the second approach... the first comparatively though looks too complex.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
Map<String, Double> map = items.stream()                       // Stream
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                            // Group to map
                 Item::getGroupName,                           // Key is the groupName
                 Collectors.averagingDouble(Item::getValue))); // Value is the average of values
```

To get result average of a particular group, get the value from the `Map`:

```
double averageForA = map.get("A");
```

Comment: this returns a `Map`, the OP is clearly not interested in such a result

Comment: The OP can get the result from the `Map` using `Map::get`.

Comment: that would be for a single group, again, not what the OP is after

Comment: One way to sort that out could be `double result = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getGroupName,Collectors.averagingDouble(Item::getValue))).entrySet().stream().mapToDouble(Map.Entry::getValue).average().orElse(Double.NaN);`. Even when the collector in your case looks easier to read, I would preferrably choose the second approach suggested in Eugene's answer(easy to read and implement).

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using [`collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)). Based on example from [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) (see `class Averager`) you can write your own class which will let you

- collect current sum and unique names
- handle each Item element to update sum and set of unique names
- combine other instances of that class in case of parallel processing.

So such class can look like

```
class ItemAverager {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet();
    double sum = 0;

    ItemAverager add(Item item) {
        set.add(item.getGroupName());
        sum += item.getValue();
        return this;
    }

    ItemAverager combine(ItemAverager ia) {
        set.addAll(ia.set);
        sum += ia.sum;
        return this;
    }

    double average() {
        if (set.size() > 0)
            return sum / set.size();
        else
            return 0; //or throw exception
    }
}
```

and can be used like

```
List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
        new Item("A", 1.0),
        new Item("A", 3.0),
        new Item("B", 1.0)
);

double avrg = items
        .stream()
        .collect(ItemAverager::new,
                 ItemAverager::add, 
                 ItemAverager::combine
        ).average();      // `collect` will return ItemAverager
                          // on which we can call average()

System.out.println(avrg); // Output: 2.5 
                          // (since 1+3+1 = 5 and there are only two groups 5/2 = 2.5)
```

---

But to be honest in case of no parallel processing I would prefer your own solution using simple loop (maybe with little improvement since you don't need to call `contains` before `add` on sets, `add` internally calls it anyway)

```
public static double  averageForGroup(List<Item> items) {
    Set<String> uniqueGroups = new HashSet<>();
    double sum = 0;
    for (Item item : items) {
        uniqueGroups.add(item.getGroupName());
        sum += item.getValue();
    }
    return sum / uniqueGroups.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double getAverageByGroups(List<Item> items) {
    Map<String, Double> map = Optional.ofNullable(items).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getGroupName, Collectors.summingDouble(Item::getValue)));
    return map.isEmpty() ? 0 : map.values().stream().mapToDouble(value -> value).sum() / map.size();
}
```

In this example `getAverageByGroups` returns `0` for empty `items`.

Comment: the OP is not looking for the average for a *single* group, read the question again